# Is it possible to get Skype video calls working in Chrome OS?

Tags: skype, google-chrome-os

Is it possible to get Skype video calls working in Chrome OS?

Comment: Maybe for the moment you try imo.im. For a current replacement

Answer (score 2):

Although Microsoft's license is still relevant, Google have created a "[packaged apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html)" API which can let developers make offline apps. If you were able to get the SkypeKit service to install/run on Chrome OS, you could then make a JavaScript API to interface with it and we'd have ourselves a base to start developing a Chrome OS Skype client.

If anyone knows a good place to discuss all the finer details, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much of an answer, but unfortunately no.

I looked into using their SkypeKit API -- a newly released API for third-party developers to add Skype support to non-Skype hardware and software products. In its license agreement is a clause that explicitly states that you (developers) are not allowed to use their SkypeKit binaries in a web browser context.

Until Skype releases these barriers, or maybe develops a Native Client plugin (à la Netflix) you're stuck using video with GTalk.

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up answer to my earlier post about Skype itself being unavailable, I recently came across WebRTC. This is an HTML5 framework designed specifically to solve your problem in a web framework.

http://www.webrtc.org/

A demo of WebRTC is in action at https://apprtc.appspot.com/. This worked great on my Samsung Series 5 Chromebook running Chrome OS 26.

If you want a more Skype-like experience, you can try vLine. This site utilizes the WebRTC framework and provides a JavaScript API to build something like a company-wide video-calling webapp.

https://vline.com/

For WebRTC to work, your communication partner needs use a WebRTC compatibile browser. Currently, only supported by Chrome 24 and Firefox 20.